# How can i make this work? I can't make the textbox values add and then display on textbox3 when button is clicked

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click
        Dim TextBox1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1)
        Dim TextBox2 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2)
        Dim TextBox3 As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3)
        TextBox3 = TextBox1 + TextBox2
```

Kinda new to programming in vb.net help would be really appreciated

```
End Sub
```

Comment: You already have a variable named `TextBox1`. It's a `TextBox`, not an `Integer`. Use different names for the integer values. Second, you can't add a `TextBox` to a `TextBox`, but you *can* add two integer values to produce a third integer value, which can then be `Convert`ed to a string and assigned to a `TextBox`.Text property.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have TextBox1, TextBox2 and TextBox3 on your form.

Try going for this:

TextBox3.Text = "" & (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))

You are currently creating 3 new variables with the names of the already existing TextBoxes.
You are also trying to read out the TextBox-Object itself as integer value which is doomed to fail since it's not an integer but a TextBox.

If you want to get the text of the TextBox use TextBox1.Text.

Ken White's comment describes your problem quite well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert anything to an integer.  This is done in your declarations.  In other words when you declare value1 as an integer and then you assign the text in textbox1 as value1, it is automatically converted to an integer if it is numeric in the first place.  The code is very simple to perform the calculation.  It is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Value1 As Integer = TextBox1.Text
    Dim Value2 As Integer = TextBox2.Text
    Dim Sum As Integer
    Sum = Value1 + Value2
    TextBox3.Text = Sum
End Sub
```

If you then want to restrict the input to numeric input you can do something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
End Sub
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile if you have `option strict on` though (which i think you should) without adding `CInt`

Comment: I don't see the value in using CInt to convert data to an integer when you can ensure that it is an integer in the first place using validation as shown in my answer above.

Comment: the value is that your code will still compile if `option strict` is on. You can never ensure `Textbox1.text`, is an `integer`, because it's a `string`. Yes, you ensure that the input is formatted as an `integer`, which is why i proposed `CInt` instead of `Integer.TryParse`, but it's still a string.

Comment: I can see that.  I almost never use option strict though.  I guess if you do need/want to have option strict on then using CInt would be the way to go.